# How to prove that a language which clones is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

I am trying to prove that the following language is regular:

*$L'$ is a clone of $L$ where $L$ is a regular language over $\{0,1\}^*$. For example, if $L=001$, then $L'=000011$.

If $L=010$, $L'=001100$. Show that $L'$ is regular.*

I know there are several methods I could use here, such as finding a regular expression, sketching a DFA/NFA or deriving a regular grammar but I am not sure how to do so for this particular language. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a clone is obtained by applying the monoid homomorphism $f:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ defined by $f(0) = 00$ and $f(1) = 11$.

Now, it is a standard result that [regular languages are closed under homomorphims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties).
In particular, the clone of a regular language is a regular language.